# Writing to a java subprocess

Tags: java, subprocess, java.util.scanner, printwriter, printstream

I'm attempting to write to the stdin of a subprocess (both are java apps).  Reading the process's output works fine, but inputting does not work using either `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter`.  Here is a sample program that I wrote to test the odd behavior, which I run with no arguments.  That then runs the same program as a subprocess.  The sub process just reads input and echoes it into the output.  The main process takes stdin and writes it to the subprocess input and outputs the subprocess output to stdout.

The trouble is, this doesn't work.  The `nextLine()` of the subprocess doesn't match with the `println()` statement in the parent process, so the subprocess never outputs anything.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it (preferably on the parent process, because I can't alter the child process of the main project).

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProcTest{
    public static Scanner stdin;
    public static String line;
    public static Process sub;

    public static BufferedReader childout;
    public static PrintWriter childin;

    public static void main(String[] args){
            stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("y")){
                    while(true){
                            line = stdin.nextLine();
                            System.out.println(line);
                    }
            }else{
                    try{
                            sub = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java ProcTest y");
                            childout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sub.getInputStream()));
                            childin = new PrintWriter(sub.getOutputStream());
                            while(true){
                                    childin.println(stdin.nextLine());
                                    childin.flush();
                                    while(childout.ready()) System.out.println( childout.readLine() );
                            }
                    }catch(IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Process handling in Java is pretty clunky. Can you just run the child process's `main` method in your parent process directly?

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause of this sort of thing is a buffering problem.

In your example program, I see one possible problem: in the child process, you are doing `System.out.println()` but not flushing afterward. Consulting the Javadoc indicates that `PrintStream`s may autoflush, but it is not specified whether the default `System.out` is so configured, so it's worth a try.

Note that some platforms decide to autoflush stdout only if it is a terminal (I don't know whether Java `System` does), which can confuse the matter when debugging.

(I do notice that you said that you can't change the child process in the real situation, but if this is what the problem is, then you *have* to change the child process (or, if there is an is-a-terminal test, wrap it in a pseudo-terminal).)

Comment: That's one of the weird things, though.  I haven't tested on this sample program, but on the main project I'm working on, the parent process still picks up the output of the child, but the child just isn't responding when the parent tries to communicate with it.  Would the parent's PrintWriter's flushing / not-flushing cause a problem with that?

Comment: The parent code is flushing, so it should be fine. There's never such a thing as too much flushing for correctness (well, unless the recipient makes the mistake of reading just what's available and incorrectly assuming it's a complete line/packet/message, which is incorrect and prone to failing under load).